# How to select two values from table where one of the values has to be distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am using this query and I need a help to rewrite it for my scenario.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sender 
FROM test_table 
WHERE ("Some condition").
```

From the above query I am getting list of distinct sender names.

But I want one more value has to shown in the table like below

```
SELECT Sender_type, DISTINCT Sender 
FROM test_table 
WHERE ("Some condition").
```

This query shows some error. So I need a to show results where sender has to be distinct values and also sender type of the corresponding sender.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? If you mention an error, please **always** post the complete and exact error message that you're getting! We can't see your screen, nor read your mind!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Sender_type, FROM test_table WHERE ("Some condition") groupby sender
```

Try this..

Comment: Why is `Sender` in brackets? `DISTINCT` applies to the whole select list. Not individual columns.

Comment: You can also apply for individual columns.I have used many times in my work.

Comment: No you can't. If there are two rows `Sender=X, Sender_type=1` and  `Sender=X, Sender_type=2` then `DISTINCT(Sender) as sender, Sender_type` will return two rows. Not one. How would it know the `Sender_type` to return in that single row?

Comment: if two rows sender=x ,sender_type=1 and sender=x , sender_type=2 then if you write this query SELECT DISTINCT sender,sender_type FROM test_table WHERE ("Some condition") then it will also give two rows..

Comment: Your fiddle just agrees with my earlier statement that `DISTINCT applies to the whole select list. Not individual columns.` I certainly never claimed anything different.

Comment: OK so you've provided two different fiddles. One with `select distinct sender , type from demo1 where sender='abc'` and the other with `select distinct( sender) as sender , type from demo1 where sender='abc'` and both of them return the exact same results. So why do you think that supports your claim that "You can also apply for individual columns"? Back to my original question. Why is Sender in brackets in your answer?

Comment: In PostgreSQL's there's a DISTINCT ON feature which allows to apply distinct on a subset of the columns, kind of returning the  "first" row from a group by rows with the same distinct values (of course the output is unpredictable and might change with the next run of the same query)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong and indeed it throws errors. You should place `DISTINCT` right after your `SELECT` command as follow and it will work for the whole select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Sender_type, Sender FROM test_table WHERE ("Some condition").
```

[**Documentation here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

To understand how the keyword "DISTINCT" works you can take a look at: http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/Selecting-Distinct-Records-From-A-Table.htm

Especially the section:

> You can also use the DISTINCT keyword for combinations of columns. It is important to understand the behavior of the keyword under those circumstances. The constraint now applies to the combination of columns, rather than the individual columns. The SQL result will be all of the unique combinations of values for those columns appearing in the table. For example, consider the SQL query below:
>   `enter code here`SELECT DISTINCT make, model FROM cars

So, your query become:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sender_type, Sender FROM test_table WHERE ("Some condition")
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT:

```
SELECT MIN(Sender_type), Sender  -- or MAX
FROM test_table 
WHERE ("Some condition")
GROUP BY Sender
```

If there are multiple Sender_Types you must decide which you want, MIN or MAX